# Angular Ionic modal (ion-modal) changes display behavior mysteriously

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic card modal overlay that's triggered by a button. When I first added it, it worked as expected. But the moment I refresh the app, it changes behavior.

This first screenshot shows the correct behavior. The modal covers part of the screen and it touches all the screen edges, except the top.

[image]

And this is how it behaves after I refresh. The modal is confined to the shrunk background, leaving spacing between the screen edges.

[image]

Here's my modal code:

```
<ion-modal #modal mode="ios" class="auto-height" trigger="open-schedule-modal" [presentingElement]="presentingElement">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Modal</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
          <ion-button (click)="modal.dismiss()">
            <ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <div class="inner-content">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          ...
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          ...
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

And the relevant SCSS:
The issue doesn't lie here because I tried removing all styling and it still occurs.

```
ion-modal.auto-height {
  &.bottom {
    align-items: flex-end;
  }

  --height: auto;

  .ion-page {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    contain: content;
    bottom: 0;

    .inner-content {
      max-height: 80vh;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the basic css is not apply to that modal. dont worry in mobile device you wont find refresh button.

Comment: Yeah but you can still refresh the app. I want to understand the root cause of the problem.

Comment: css is your issue here, its not being applied when refresh. Like the previous comment above, you don't need to worry about refresh. your users aren't going to be refreshing the app.

Comment: Thats normal when you refresh. Not only for modals but also in general i had issues with labels and inputs. 
 Make the full testing lifecycle as a normal user not as a developer. Users cant refresh the app.

Answer (score 1):

When initially loading the ‘app’, at browser launch, your developer tools aren’t active. Ionic selects an ‘theme’ based on your device. If you inspect your page you’ll see that the gets the ‘md’ with ‘platform-core’ classs (and some more stuff) at startup. When using the developer tools with the device mode enabled and you refresh at that point, the app reloads and the class is set again based on your ‘selected device’. In your case iPhone 6/7/8. You’ll now have e.g. ‘ios’ and ‘platform-ios’ and more set. This is giving you that ‘css error’.

This is not an error btw. You’ll just have to implement some platform specific css tweaks. That will fix your problem.

Try using:
ionic serve --lab
You’ll be able to view multiple platforms and it’s styles. This way you’ll be able to inspect them easily and create platform specific css tweaks easier.